# Java JDBC, viewing the columns of the table that the user specifies

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

I am thinking about the design of the method that will enable the user to potentially pass a list of integers that indicate the columns that the user wishes to retrieve from the database.

I do not want to hardcode multiple methods that esentially do the same thing, i.e. show the user different columns but from the same table.

here is the code from Oracle tutorials on retrieving the values using JDBC:

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
        "SALES, TOTAL " +
        "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                               "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                               "\t" + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

So the query is not a problem, the column names can be concatenated, depending on which columns the user wants to see. The issue is in the try block. How does one .get the correct format from the result set? Or should I simply use the String for every column? Or should I hardcode all the table columns (rs.get depending on what data type the column is) and then in println return only the columns that the user wishes to see (actually how would I do that)? Well, I guess you understand my issue.

Comment: the easy way is, you can set parameter as an array for columns and getString for all results

Comment: Use a second loop to loop over the columns and `getString` should do the job since you only need to display it to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve all the data from the particular table and use it to populate a collection of the appropriate object. And then based on the user's choice, you could just print out the appropriate columns.

Assuming you know how to create the collection of the appropriate object, I will explain how you can do the next step.

You can display a message to the user asking him to enter the columns he wishes to see. Like, Enter 1 to see the coffee name, 2 to see the supplier id, 3 to see the price etc. and 0 to view the data.

So you basically keep reading the int's until the user enters a 0. Once he enters a zero, display the requested values.